# Difference between Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer') and Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, core

What is difference between `Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer')` and `Mage::getModel('core/email_template');`?

Comment: Please explain what you want to know. Was the answer given by Anshu what you expected? Or do you know how magento resolved class names and you want to know what the difference between the classes is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mage::getModel() is used for creating objects of model classes.

> Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer') will create object for
>   class app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php

> Mage::getModel('core/email_template') will create object for class
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

For more details and methods they contain, you can see these classes at their respective locations as mentioned. 
You can always read Mage::getModel() like below

> Mage::getModel('classGroupName/path_to_model_file');

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [core/email_template_mailer](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer.html) and [core/email_template](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.html) it seems that the first one has methods to send the template that you generate using the second one. I'd guess someone else can explain it a bit more but that seems to be what is happening to me.